# Testing Action Mailbox controller using raw email source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action-mailbox

I'm having a problem where email attachments aren't coming through for certain emails, but are for others. I'm trying to figure out what's different about the emails that aren't working.

Is it possible to write a test for an Action Mailbox controller where the `Mail` object I'm using gets generated from a raw email body, so that I can recreate the email conditions as close to reality as possible?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `from_source`:

```
source = File.read("some_email_source.txt")
process(Mail.from_source(source))
```

Comment: This is cool, but where is `process` defined - how to do this in rspec?

Comment: Its an instance method on , type: :mailbox in rspec